# Sending config/state to device from firebase function via google iot with Qos 0

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-iot

Is there any method to publish data to device from firebase function with qos 0.

Answer (score 0):

There is [an example of using a Google Cloud Function to publish a configuration change to a device](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/community/tree/master/tutorials/iot-device-to-device/dev2dev). That same function should be easy to translate to Firebase functions if that's where you're looking to run it.